# Django does not support REST request Content-type header as "multipart/form-data"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

On the server side, `Django` rest server is configured with following parsers in `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    )
}
```

When I send a request from a client with the content-type header as `"multipart/form-data"`, it is not resolving the request data sent from the client (file upload).
In the debug mode, `request.FILES` is coming as empty.

If I send the same request without the content-type header, the request object contains the File upload data (success case).
In the debug mode, `request.FILES` contains the files uploaded.

We have many REST clients and I cannot force the clients not to set the content-type header.

Why is `Django` not able to resolve multipart data when the content-type header `"multipart/form-data"` ?

Am I missing any configuration here?

Comment: How did you sent data? Through POSTMAN tool?

Comment: What is the front end tool used? Is it a POST request or PUT request?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Postman to test. And it is a POST request.